# Конечно же(,) в школе!

Tags: пунктуация

> — Где научиться промышленному программированию на языке Python?
>
> — Конечно же(,) в школе!

Нужна ли запятая? Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, запятая не нужна! Цитирую [Грамоту](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_363):

> При употреблении в ответной реплике, произносимой тоном уверенности, убежденности, слово «конечно» может не обособляться: *«Это правда?» – «**Конечно** правда!»*

Comment: Из "Грамоты" следует, что в данном случае "конечно же" может не обособляться! Т. е. можно не обособлять, а можно... ОБОСОБИТЬ? Обособление не будет ошибкой?

Comment: Вы меня озадачили! Видимо, можно, но я бы не стал... Без "же" мне запятая видится более допустимой. Но и то при восклицательной интонации и знаке я бы не стал стал ставить.

Comment: Артем, у вас все правильно. Читается без паузы с одним ударением: Конечно прАвда! А если поставить запятую, то надо ставить два ударения в такой короткой фразе (такое чтение просто невозможно даже при отсутствии ЖЕ). А вообще в других предложениях обособление возможно: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=конечно+же